# How to "hide/show" the "Expandable Item" component (quasar) from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, store, quasar

I want to be able to hide/show the component in question, but from another component

Something like

-dropdown.Vue

```
  <q-expansion-item
    expand-separator
    icon="perm_identity"
    label="Account settings"
    caption="John Doe"
  >
    <q-card>
      <q-card-section>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, eius reprehenderit eos corrupti
        commodi magni quaerat ex numquam, dolorum officiis modi facere maiores architecto suscipit iste
        eveniet doloribus ullam aliquid.
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </q-expansion-item>
```

closeDrop.Vue

```
<script>
    methods: {
      click() {
         expansion-item.hide
      }

    }
 </script>
```

Take in account that there is already @hide and @show methods in the component, but I weren't totally able to manage it from vuex!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `v-model` as explained in https://quasar.dev/vue-components/expansion-item#Controlling-expansion-state:

```
<q-expansion-item
  v-model="expanded"
  icon="perm_identity"
  label="Account settings"
  caption="John Doe"
>
```

And in your script add an `expanded` variable to your data:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    expanded: false
  })
}
```

You can now toggle the expanded state by simply modifying the value of `expanded`:

```
this.expanded = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it using the ref attribute, and calling it with "this.$refs.expandableItem.hide()